# Как лечить ошибку сборки They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context?

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Пытаюсь получить разрешение экрана через `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` и `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`:

```
using System.Windows;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int cellsize = 32;
        int gridWidth = (int)(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / cellsize);
        int gridHeight = (int)(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / cellsize);
        string terminalConfig = "window: size="+
            gridWidth+"x"+gridHeight+
            ", cellsize="+cellsize+"x"+cellsize+";" +
            "0x66: C:/Users/Risto/Documents/Projects/Pokuland/media/floor.png, resize="+
            cellsize+"x"+cellsize+";";
...
    }
}
```

Они доступны в пространстве имён `System.Windows` и требуют решение PresentationFramework. Подключаю решение через встроенный в VS менеджер пакетов NuGet и получаю ошибку сборки:

> System.BadImageFormatException: "Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)"

Как правильно подключить или использовать это решение, чтобы ошибки не было? Что вообще означает эта ошибка? Как можно получить размеры экрана другим способом, если проблема (вдруг) нерешаема?

Comment: Что за тип проекта?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Console Application.+ библиотека BearLib (http://foo.wyrd.name/ru:bearlibterminal:reference)

Comment: Я бы создал WPF проект, поудалял бы все лишнее, воткнул бы туда Program.cs, потом изменил бы тип сборки на консольное приложение. Получилось бы консольное приложение со всеми референсами WPF.

Comment: @aepot это и правда помогло, спасибо,но хотелось бы узнать, как делать такие изменения проекта руками, так что вопрос остаётся актуальным.

Comment: Все эти настройки в cproj файле. Он xml, его можно редактировать.

Comment: Любопытно, а почему вы хотите использовать в своем проекте библиотеку, которая для него не предназначена? Вам нужны все контролы, что в нем есть, методы, предназначенные для WPF? Я думаю, что 99.9% из нее вы даже не будете использовать, ну так какой смысл тогда? Посмотрите из чего она [состоит](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/SystemParameters.cs,f5e6ee10e10d5e43,references) и вы поймете, что там `P/Invoke`, который вызывает методы OS, так почему не использовать сразу их?

Comment: Ок, можете пойти вообще по пути WMI и написать например [так](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnzyIF) (ошибку не смотрите, ибо там не Win). В любом случае, решать подобное библиотеками, которые созданы не для вашего типа проекта, которые содержат в себе уйму лишнего, как-то не правильно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тогда такой вопрос: а есть ли кросс платформенное решение этой задачи, или я слишком много хочу?

Comment: А это уже другой вопрос, ибо даже приложенный вами код работает исключительно под windows. Скорей всего надо писать методы под каждую os отдельно, либо искать сторонние решения, которые сделают это за вас. В любом случае, все, что в этом вопросе и комментариях относится только под windows.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тогда комментарии с двумя вариантами решения оформите, как ответ, пожалуйста, я приму.

Comment: А какой вы от меня ответ ожидаете? Вот у вас вопрос "как лечить ошибку сборки", а я вам скажу "ей, а зачем тебе это, используй лучше то-то". Разве это является ответом на поставленный вопрос? Вон решение от @aepot косвенно, да, решает вашу задачу, но не объясняет почему это так и что надо делать на чистом консольном приложении. Так что, я ответ, пожалуй, давать не буду, можете его составить самостоятельно. Советы по решению вашей задачи дал и этого думаю достаточно)